# visual studio statically linked application way too small

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-linking

I am building a win32 application in C++. I have two static lib projects (open source libs) that I am compiling and using in the application. The static libraries for these projects are both over 50MB. However, my executable is only 3MB. This doesn't seem right, even though if I copy the executable (only) over to another machine everything seems to run fine.

I have followed all of the visual studio instructions for VS2010 static linking a project. i.e. Properties->Framework And References-> Adding the static lib project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A static link will include just the parts you're using from the libraries, so it could easily be that your executable is much smaller than the libraries.

Comment: @SteveTownsend where can I find the linker map?

Comment: So I guess in a way, you could theoretically use much less space by using a static link instead of dynamic?

Comment: You have to tell the linker to generate it. as here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The map shows the symbols. So that is definitely it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Unused methods are removed usually by the linker when an executable is produced. However, when producing a static lib, it is impossible to determine which methods are needed, so all of them are included in the library. Only when the executable is produced are the methods from the lib that are really used determined, the others are removed.